# How to create a game trainer in python using pointer and offset

Tags: python

Hi guys I would like to make my first game trainer in python. I am using the Pymem library for editing the memory. Initially, I found pointers using a cheat engine and it works when I open the game and finds the address of the variables. But I would like to do it programmatically using python and make a game trainer with python so i need to write code to get pointers (or addresses). How to to use a pointer with offset, all while pointer changes during the game so that I can modify variables of the game. Thank you and sorry for my bad english :)

Example:

```
import pymem
import pymem.process
import pymem.memory

process = pymem.process
mem = pymem.memory



DMC5 = pymem.Pymem("ac_client.exe")
DMC5_base = DMC5.process_handle


adress = 0x029AA270
value = 99

mem.write_int(DMC5_base, adress, value)
```

The varable Address change when reopen the game, therefore my question is, how get the new address value or a pointer to write the variable again?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1M7eOXL_tE

Comment: Just for information, any code example that you have tried would motivate others to help you more and provide  a better context.

Comment: For example if i have the address 00D9A270 in cheat engine, when i close the game and  run it again, this code change, therefore how can i get a static address or how can i calculate the new address with a pointer and offset in game trainer?